# Retrieve URL from Google Places API photo Response

Tags: node.js, google-places-api, facebook-chatbot

I am working with a bot platform where I have to supply an image URL to display images.

Google Places Photo Response is an image rather than a URL. Any way to retrieve an URL?

I am using NodeJs request

```
var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo',
  qs: 
  { maxwidth: '400',
    photoreference: photoreference,
    key: Google_Places_KEY },
  };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
 // Code goes here. 
 });
```

My solution right now is to upload the photo to my server, create an URL and supply that. Is there a better workaround?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this?

Comment: No. The easiest way I found is to store the photo in S3 and use the image.